# how to get last date form DB table mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

i have this table in my DB

categoriesSupports-> id, category_id, support_id, date

the thing is that i need to extract all support_id where date is the closest date from now...

something like this... if there is in the DB table

```
id, category_id, support_id, date
1       1             1       2010-11-23
2       1             2       2010-11-25
3       1             1       2010-11-26
4       1             3       2010-11-24
```

i need to get just

```
id, category_id, support_id, date
2       1             2       2010-11-25
3       1             1       2010-11-26
4       1             3       2010-11-24
```

So for better undestanding... i need **the closest date** for **each support** and i only have date from the past...
Ive being trying a lot and I dont know how...

Comment: You need to define what "closest" means.  That is a very open term.

Comment: @Brettski No it isn't. See my answer to understand why.

Comment: @juan Do you have future dates in your table?

Comment: hahaha closest for me means the nearest date to now... by that i ment if today is 26 the closest dates for those supports are 25/26/24 because 23 for support 1 is far than 26

Comment: You mean in the last 3 days from today? Even if nothing is in there?

Comment: no i dont have future dates... just passed dates... @Alin Purcaru @Brettski your answer only return the really closest dates so in my example it will only return id=3

Comment: @juan You should rephrase *date is the closest date from now...* because my original answer was for this exact expression which means to get entries that are in the same date as the most recent date **that has entries**, this approach would guarantee you that you get something even if there were no rows added in a while. I added an alternative that gets entries in the last 3 days if that is what you really need.

Comment: @juan So now you need for `each support id`? Please restructure your question and post a final version...

Comment: @juan, you need to CLARIFY your question, seems everyone is confused what `closest` means, determine that for a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A. This answers 'where date is the closest date from now...':

```
SELECT *
FROM `categoriesSupports`
WHERE `date` IN (
    SELECT `date`
    FROM `categoriesSupports`
    ORDER BY `date` DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Notes:

1. You can set `LIMIT n` to select entries for more dates.
2. If you only want for the last date you can replace `IN` with `=` because the sub-select will return only one value.
3. If your table includes future dates replace `ORDER BY date DESC` with `ORDER BY ABS(NOW() - date) ASC`.

---

A solution with JOINS. Will work only if you have past dates.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM `categoriesSupports` AS a
LEFT JOIN `categoriesSupports` AS b
    ON b.date > a.date
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

*Added just for reference.*

---

### B. This answers 'where date is in the last 3 days (including today)':

```
SELECT *
FROM `categoriesSupports`
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), `date`) < 3
```

Replace `3` with any number if you want more or less days.

---

### C. Same as A., but per support id

```
SELECT a.*
FROM `categoriesSupports` AS a
LEFT JOIN `categoriesSupports` AS b
    ON b.support_id = a.support_id AND b.date > a.date
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

*This answers the latest version of the question.*

Comment: @Roopesh I added a note on how to change the first query to work with future dates too, but I doubt he needs that. The second query is just for reference, it shouldn't be used in favor of the first.

Comment: @alin this will only return id=3 for my example above... I need to get the closest pass date for each support

Comment: @alin no no... if you do your very first answer it will only return 2010-11-26 dates from the table, beacuase thats the really closest date from today... but if i have other support with date 2010-11-25 the query will not return that support because is not searching for other supports with other closest dates...

Comment: just see my example above and the hoped variables to be return and you will understand what i mean

Comment: @juan Then use option **B**. I gave you a lot of alternatives. Use the one that suits you.

Comment: @juan It should work. Do you get an error? Does it select something?

Comment: it select just the rows with the highest date... by that i mean it select just the ones supports with date 2010-11-26... can i filter that by support_id too? sorry im not using B im using the one with join

Comment: @juan Use **C**. And the next time try to post your requirements as clear as possible and from the start.

Comment: @alin youre a genius thanks very much... sorry its 3 am and i havent sleep in 46 hours

Comment: @juan No problem. Also on SO it is customary to vote and accept answers that help you. So... at least for the effort :)

Comment: @Alin.. the query is right if there is no future date :). However your 3rd comment (which you striked out) will actually be useful to others who refer to this question. Could you unstrike it? Its actually correct and will work in both cases so it is more generic.

Answer (score 2):

The following should give you:

1. all the categoriesSupports for current date(one or multiple)
2. One previous categoriesSupport(if exists)
3. One future categoriesSupport(if exists)

   ```
   (
     SELECT *
     FROM `categoriesSupports`
     WHERE `date` < CURDATE()
     ORDER BY `date` DESC
     LIMIT 1
   )

   UNION

   (
     SELECT *
     FROM `categoriesSupports`
     WHERE `date` = CURDATE()
   )

   UNION

   (
     SELECT *
     FROM `categoriesSupports`
     WHERE `date` > CURDATE()
     ORDER BY `date` ASC
     LIMIT 1
   )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM CurrentDeals
WHERE (julianday(Date('now')) - julianday(date))<=3
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Here, you have to decide what would be your meaning of "closest". I have used 3 as the sample. This will list out the records, which has a date value lesser that or equal to 3.

Hope this is what you wanted.